# css disappearing in iframes in IE

Tags: css, iframe

on reload of jsp page , the css disappears in iframes. Before reloading the page, the css effects are shown so path is not wrong but as page is reloaded, css disappears. I know frames should not be used. But used it because it was convenient to show multiple pages on a window. Please can someone explain why CSS is disappearing and its solution.

Comment: This is unusual. Please provide an example or some code so that we have something to work with.

Answer (score 0):

If the page loaded in the iframe is from a different domain than the main page, then you may be seeing the effects of the browser's protection mechanisms against cross-domain scripting.